# Python Random Number Generator Errors

Tags: python

Hello I just started programming in Python and I was just trying to make a RNG but there are some errors that I don't understand.

Here's the code

```
import random
import time

numbersGenerated = 0

print('Hello! How many numbers do you want?')
numbersNeeded = input()
print('What would you like the minimum for the numbers be?')
Min = input()
print('And the maximum?')
Max = input()

numbersNeeded = str(numbersNeeded)
numbersGenerated = str(numbersGenerated)

while numbersGenerated < numbersNeeded:
    number = random.randint(Min, Max)
    number = int(number)

    numbersGenerated = numbersGenerated + 1

    print(number)
    print()
    time.sleep(2)

print('All done. Hope to see you again!')
```

The Traceback Error says

```
File "C:/Python32/Number_Generator.py", line 20, in <module>
number = random.randint(Min, Max)    
File "C:\Python32\lib\random.py", line 215, in randint
return self.randrange(a, b+1)
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

I have changed lines thirteen and  to int also but that didn't change the outcome.

Answer (score 4):

1. You are doing `while numbersGenerated < numbersNeeded` when `numbersGenerated` and `numbersNeeded` are strings, which is probably not what you wanted.
2. You are calling `random.randint(Min, Max)` while `Min` and `Max` are strings, they should be integers.
3. No need for `number = int(number)`, it will already be an int.
4. `numbersGenerated = numbersGenerated + 1` again, the variable is a string

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3, you should convert the input from `input` explicitly:

```
Min = int(input())
```

and

```
Max = int(input())
```